# Can somebody help me with List Comprehension for below code?

Tags: python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

```
total_login=Queryset
this_month = datetime.now().month
this_month_login = 0
last_month_login = 0
second_last_month_login = 0
if total_login:
    for i in total_login:
        if i.created_at.month==this_month:
            this_month_login+=1
        if i.created_at.month==this_month-1:
            last_month_login+=1
        if i.created_at.month==this_month-2:
            second_last_month_login+=1
```

Also, if I want to automate the number of months of data, how are we going to do this? Like say for n months instead of just last two months.

Comment: can you share sample input?

Comment: @segFaulter Sample input as in? It is a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to first group each item by month and the count them. Something like this:

```
Queryset.objects.all().values_list('created_at__month').annotate(total_item=Count('id'))
```

And then process the result and extract the month you need.

Comment: Sorry not this method.